# Minimax Alpha Beta Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I think I've finally got my head around the minimax and Alpha beta pruning but implementing it is a whole other story!

From my understanding the basics are: 
You assign a heuristic function score to certain moves (Gomoku as an example).

- If there are 5 in a row we should assign a high value like 9999 since
  this is a winning move.
- If we have 4 in a row we with two open ends
  we should assign a high value again because it is impossible to block
  this move and etc etc

My problem comes when we actually have to implement this in Java!

I have a Color [][] board (8x8) where black is player 1 and white is player 2 and null indicates an empty space, I'm confused about how we would

1. Search the board to find the opposition moves and assign values
   to them
2. Search the board to find MY moves and assign values to
   them
3. Then pick the best possible move (which I think I could do
   If I knew how the first 2 worked since this is basically the
   Algorithm).

Some help and guidance is appreciated! I've looked at YouTube tutorials, lecture notes from various online sources but none of them are really making sense to me when it comes to physically writing the code.

If it makes a difference the game is Gomoku played on an 8x8 board

Answer (score 2):

## Define State

First you have to define state of the game. In your example, it would be 2d-array representing configuration of the board.

Create a java class which stores the game configuration and board state. This class will now become the node of your minimax tree.

## Define children

After defining the node of minimax tree, you have to define children as per rules of the game. This represents your moves.

With this you have minimax tree!

> Search the board to find the opposition moves and assign values to them

For assigning values of each board configurations, store it in class itself. Also you don't have to search the board to find opposition moves, as it are represented by your children. [Note that board is stored with each class]

> Search the board to find MY moves and assign values to them

Again, if given class represents player-1 move, then children represents player-2 moves.

> Then pick the best possible move

This is defined by the algorithm. If you are in max node, you select the move which correspond to maximum value. i.e you select highest valued children.
In case of min node, you select the minimum valued children.

**PS**: You don't have to define entire minimax tree before hand. It can be dynamically created while doing dfs. This will significantly reduce memory.

**PPS**: Refer [Chess Programming](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/) for more details.

Comment: When you say store the game configuration, do you just mean store what pieces are where on the board?

Comment: Yes, you can store what pieces are on the board. By game configuration, I meant, things which can describe the game state at any point. You can store the score of each player, feature values (like 5 in row etc).